# Kivy add items to accordion programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, accordion

I have a simple tabbed application.
Now in every tab i am going to have an accordion

I have created the layout in a *.kv file.
Now my question is (might be a stupid one but i am fairly new on how kivy works): How can i add items and sub items in the accordion i created.

In this example i am building a tv viewing app.
So for example Live Tv will have the accordion titles as the groups of the channels and inside the channels (which i am going to get from a db)

Here is my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem


class LiveTV(Accordion):
    def ListItems(self):
        root = Accordion()
        for x in range(1, 3, 1):
            item = AccordionItem(title='Page % d' % x)
            root.add_widget(item)
        return root


class Display(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Display, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        rootAc = LiveTV.ListItems(self)


class IptvApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1366')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '768')
        Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
        # Change to auto for full screen app
        Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
        # Maximized for full resolution app
        Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'visible')
        # To remove right click orange dot (touch emulation)
        Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
        Config.write()
        return Display()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    IptvApp().run()
```

And here is my *.kv file

```
<Button>:
font_size: 40
color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
size_hint: 0.4, 0.05

<Display>
    tab_width: 600
    size_hint: 1, 1
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Live TV'
        FloatLayout:
            Accordion:
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
                pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                orientation: 'vertical'
                AccordionItem:
                    title: 'Plot'
                AccordionItem:
                    title: 'Number'
                AccordionItem:
                    title: 'Another number'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Video On Demand'
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                pos_hint: {"top": 0.4, "right": 0.7}
                text: 'Button that does nothing'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Series'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Settings'
```

And here is the display:
[image: Display]

How can target programmatically that accordion i did in the *.kv file so i can populate with items and sub items?

Regards,

Comment: You must add an id for your `Accordion` (e.g. `id: channels`) and then access it through `app.root.ids.channels`..

Comment: can you please explain on my example

Comment: You must add to your code the part that you add your widgets, so we can see what (and how) are you trying to do..

Comment: if figured out with you pushing me in the right direction! @noEmbryo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out. For all those who end up here this is how its done:

in the kv file the element you want to target programmatically add an new property id i.e. for example

```
Button:
    id: btn_submit
```

and in the parent "class" in my case `<Display>` define that element i.e.

```
<Display>
    btnSubmit: btn_submit
```

Now in python code where class Display is defined you can target the button by simply writing: `self.btnSubmit.*` you can for example add_widget or anything you want.